trying to expose external secrets as env variables in my helm charts but it isnt successfull
We have setup the base of our helm-charts and now we require to set up an external secret named "SecretStore" that needs to be exposed as environment variables so my spring boot app can use it.
There has been no issue in retrieving the secret using kubectl -n default get secrets.
I have referred this secret in my deployment.yaml and helm-release.yaml but it is not fetched properly. when i do a describe deployment i get the env variable as
Environment:
DEMO_ENVRIONMENT:              sit
ENCRYPT_RANDOM_DELAY_ENABLED:  false
M_USERNAME:               map[secretKeyRef:map[key:musername name:common-credential-store]]
The files are as below
values.yaml
# Default values for helm-guestbook.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

env:
  ENCRYPT_RANDOM_DELAY_ENABLED: "false"
  DEMO_ENVRIONMENT: "sit"
secrets:
  common:
    name: common-credential-store
    key: mtoken
  api:
    name: common-credential-store
    key: musername


Deloyment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      containers:
      - name: microservice
        # example ECR link below, replace with yours.
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        # image: <ECR_LINK>/sample-encryption-ms:1.0
        env:
          {{- range $key, $val := .Values.secrets }}
          - name: {{ $key }}
            {{- if $val.name}}
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ $val.name }}
                key: {{ $val.key }}
            {{- end}}
          {{- end}}

          {{- range $key, $val := .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $val | quote }}
          {{- end }}


Helm-Release.yaml
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease

spec:
  values:
   
    secrets:
      common:
        name: common-credential-store
        key: mtoken
      api:
        name: common-credential-store
        key: musername
    env:
      DEMO_ENVRIONMENT: "sit"
      M_USERNAME:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: common-credential-store
          key: musername
    

Somehow post git reconciling on my server when i do a describe deployment I can the environment variable as
Environment:
DEMO_ENVRIONMENT:              sit
M_USERNAME:               map[secretKeyRef:map[key:musername name:common-credential-store]]
Its not fetching the actual value. Can someone help over this

It worked with the below setup.
Deployment.yml (under env section):
    env:
      {{- range $key, $val := .Values.env }}
      - name: {{ $key }}
        value: {{ $val | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- range $key, $val := .Values.secrets}}
        {{- if $val.name}}
      - name: {{ $key}}
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: {{ $val.name}}
            key: {{ $val.key}}
        {{- end}}
      {{- end}}

helm-release.yml (under values)
secrets:
  M_USERNAME:
    name: common-credential-store
    key: musername
env:
  DEMO_ENVRIONMENT: "sit"


When you iterate through .Values.env, the template code in the question always produces a simple fixed-string value.  You can't provide more complex settings with this code.
- name: {{ $key }}
  value: {{ $val | quote }}

What you're seeing in the output is a default Go representation of the structured value.
In the template code, though, the block right above that constructs a set of environment variables with valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: } which matches the structure you need.  In the FluxCD settings you can move this variable setting under secrets:, matching the structure of what's expected in the code.
spec:
  values:
    secrets:
      M_USERNAME:
        name: common-credential-store
        key: musername
      # and other ENV_VAR: { name:, key: } for values from Secrets
    env:
      DEMO_ENVIRONMENT: sit
      # and other fixed ENV_VAR: value settings

As a very specific alternative in this very specific setup, note in the template code that secrets: get rendered first and then env:, and that you already set an environment variable $api from the same secret value.  Kubernetes has syntax to set one environment variable to another's value.  In this very specific context, you can also set
spec:
  values:
    secrets:
      api:
        name: common-credential-store
        key: musername
    env:
      M_USERNAME: "$(api)"

Helm doesn't do anything in particular with the $(ENV_VAR) syntax, so it will get passed on to Kubernetes, which will interpolate it at deployment time.
Note that this setup is very specific to this Helm chart; other charts that consume .Values differently might need different settings.  The template code is very close to reading Kubernetes YAML directly out of .Values and rendering it, and you may consider whether your CI system can directly produce the YAML without going through a Helm templating layer.

Hi @David Maze - I did try it as above to give the reference in helmrelease.yaml as "$(common)" but it  still has referenced in my deployment.yaml as below
Helmrelease.yaml
secrets:
common:
name: common-credential-store
key: mtoken
api:
name: common-credential-store
key: musername
env:
ENCRYPT_RANDOM_DELAY_ENABLED: "false"
DEMO_ENVRIONMENT: "sit"
M_USERNAME: "$(common)"
-- contd in next comment

Deployment.yaml
spec:
containers:
- env:
- name: DEMO_ENVRIONMENT
value: sit
- name: ENCRYPT_RANDOM_DELAY_ENABLED
value: "false"
- name: M_USERNAME
value: $(common)
Are we supposed to provide anything else in deployment.yaml for the secrets as well?

Also I could see the yaml is executed in alphabetical order with env executed first which also aligns to why common wasnt rendered ? @david-maze

Yes, if you specify an environment variable with a reference like value: $(common), that string will appear in the helm template output unmodified.  It will also be in the Deployment and Pod specs in the cluster.  Kubernetes will expand that value when it sets up the pod environment as it creates a container.

I have set up an endpoint in my springboot app to fetch this env variable and the output of the same also has it like a reference :(
O/P -> ". This is the MTokem $(common)" --
@david-maze
